# error with deploying an Angular universal app to firebase using @angular/fire

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angular-universal

I use `@angular/fire:deploy` to deploy an Angular universal app to firebase. and then I run `ng deploy`.
it builds the browser bundles successfully, but fails to build the server bundles, due to a mistake in reading the typescrit files.
although it runs `ng run cms:server:production --bundleDependencies` successfully.

I use `@angular-builders/custom-webpack` as a builder for `build` and `server`, to use a custom webpack

angular.json

```
{
 "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {
            "ssr": true
          }
        },
"server": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "projects/cms/server/webpack.config.ts"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/cms/core/server",
            "main": "projects/cms/server/express.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/cms/server/tsconfig.json",
            "externalDependencies": [
              "firebase",
              "@firebase/app",
              "@firebase/analytics",
              "@firebase/auth",
              "@firebase/component",
              "@firebase/database",
              "@firebase/firestore",
              "@firebase/functions",
              "@firebase/installations",
              "@firebase/messaging",
              "@firebase/storage",
              "@firebase/performance",
              "@firebase/remote-config",
              "@firebase/util"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "outputHashing": "media",
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/cms/config/env.ts",
                  "with": "projects/cms/config/env.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "sourceMap": false,
              "optimization": true
            }
          }
        },
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser",
          "options": {
            "customWebpackConfig": {
              "path": "projects/cms/browser/webpack.config.ts"
            },
            "outputPath": "dist/cms/core/browser",
            "index": "projects/cms/browser/index.html",
            "main": "projects/cms/browser/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "projects/cms/browser/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "projects/cms/browser/tsconfig.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "projects/cms/browser/favicon.ico",
              "projects/cms/browser/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
              "projects/cms/browser/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/cms/config/env.ts",
                  "with": "projects/cms/config/env.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },

}
```

server/webpack.config.ts
(this file is read by `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:server`)

```
import { join } from 'path';
import {
  getConfig as basicConfig,
  ConfigOptions,
  Configuration,
  CustomWebpackBrowserSchema,
  TargetOptions
} from '../webpack.config';

export default function(
  config: Configuration,
  options: ConfigOptions = {},
  targetOptions?: TargetOptions
): Configuration {
  return getConfig(config);
}
// ... rest of the file
```

but I got this error

```
projects/cms/server/webpack.config.ts:6:20 - error TS7006: Parameter 'config' implicitly has an 'any' type.

6 function default_1(config, options = {}, targetOptions) {
```